# Precedence among plugins when choosing view

Tags: grails, grails3

I have a rather monolithic Grails 2 application that I am attempting to upgrade to Grails 3 (specifically 3.2.7) and refactor into a set of plugins - the current app uses various services on Amazon AWS, I want to refactor it so I can more easily switch to Microsoft Azure or OpenStack.

At present, the big app uses various plugins including Spring Security UI, and the app overrides some of the GSP views from the plugin with its own.  In the refactored scenario I have the main app (which will implement the AWS-specific bits), depending on a "core" plugin (with the cloud-agnostic functions) which in turn depends on spring-security-ui.  The problem I'm having is that when I put my custom `auth.gsp` view in the "core" plugin rather than in the top-level app, it no longer overrides the s2ui version of the same view.  If I copy the "core" plugin's `auth.gsp` to the same location in the top-level app, it overrides correctly.

In general, if I have *app* depends-on *plugin1* depends-on *plugin2*, is there a way to ensure that when I run the *app*, views provided by *plugin1* take precedence over the same views provided by *plugin2*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core plugin will need to specify it should be loaded after spring security ui. You can do that with:

```
def loadAfter = ['springSecurityUi']
```

This is documented here: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html#understandingPluginLoadOrder

Comment: I thought I'd tried this previously and it failed, but it turns out the failure was due to another bug.  Thanks for the pointer.